# d3: How to append nested elements on enter()? My elements get appended, but subsequent select doesn't see them

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tomaskafka/w1acm8ox/

This is my update loop:

```
var output = d3.select('#output')
    .selectAll('p')
    .data(data)
    ;

output
    .enter()
        .append('p')
        .call(function(parent) {
            parent.append('a')
        });
        ;

output
    .exit()
        .remove()
    ;

// PROBLEM: at this point, element addded right now isn't selected, and so it's attr and text isn't set.
output
    .select('a')
        .attr('href', function(d) { return 'http://www.google.com?q=' + d; })
        .text(function(d) { return d; })
    ;
```

Could you please help? I understand that due to some optimization, d3 doesn't update the DOM right away, what is then the proper way to add nested element and set it's properties on update?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the update, enter, exit pattern correctly.

Your enter selection is appended:

```
output
    .enter()
        .append('p')
        .call(function(parent) {
            parent.append('a')
        });
```

But, then you run into problems here:

```
output
    .select('a')
        .attr('href', function(d) { return 'http://www.google.com?q=' + d; })
        .text(function(d) { return d; })
    ;
```

Only elements that existed at the time the selection was created will be updated. So your newly created elements, part of the enter selection, are unaffected. This is the update selection, mutually exclusive from the enter selection - *this is different than in v3 and requires the use of the merge method to combine the update selection with the enter selection*.

This is why you have to use the timeout - the first time you run the update function the features are appended, the second time they are updated.

Instead try:

```
output
  .enter()
    .append('p')
    .call(function(parent) { parent.append('a') })
  .merge(output).select('a')
    .attr('href', function(d) { return 'http://www.google.com?q=' + d; })
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

The enter selection will result in `p`s being appended, then we merge the enter and the update selections so that all elements are updated with specific text. Now you can remove the timeout function and when moving the slider, updates should show properly.

Here's a snippet of the update:

```js
var items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]

var slider = d3.select('#slider')
 .attr('min', 0)
 .attr('max', items.length)
 .attr('value', items.length - 1)
 .attr('step', 1)
 .attr('disabled', null) // enable
 ;

function update(data) {
 var output = d3.select('#output')
  .selectAll('p')
  .data(data)
  ;

 output
  .enter()
   .append('p')
   .call(function(parent) {
    parent.append('a')
   })
      .merge(output).select('a')
   .attr('href', function(d) { return 'http://www.google.com?q=' + d; })
   .text(function(d) { return d; });
   ;

 output
  .exit()
   .remove()
  ;
}
update(['a', 'b', 'c']);

slider.on('input', function() {
 var val = +this.value;
 var newData = items.slice(0, val);

 update(newData);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
 }

 p {
  outline: 1px red solid;
 }
 a {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 1px blue solid;
  min-width: 1em;
  min-height: 1em;
 }

 .small {
  font-size: 66%;
 }

 #slider {
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
 <input type="range" id="slider" disabled="disabled" />
 <div class="small" id="output">static content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! For both solution and link to SO documentation - this is a first place that clearly mentions that selections in D3 v4 work differently (most of tutorials are for v3). Awesome, problem fixed :). Thanks again!